# Can I send an UPDATE to PostgreSQL in Python, and move on before waiting for the request to complete?

Tags: python, postgresql, nlp, sql-update, psycopg2

I am developing a high-throughput multiprocessing/clustered natural language preprocessing system, and I would like to send an UPDATE statement to my database (this is a very large update request, it is updating 100s of rows with data), and move on to the next set of pre-processing without waiting for the UPDATE to complete. The database will handle the update, but I want to move on to the next set of NLP work.

I think it might be possible to do it with some sort of asynchronous request, but one which isn't blocking.

How can I do this? I am using psycopg2 to talk to my database.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-support

Comment: What if the update still has not finished by the time you want to send the next one?

Comment: @jjanes the updates are not related. It won’t be a problem if UPDATE 1 does not complete before UPDATE 2

Comment: It *will* be a problem if the connection is reused when it is not in a state suitable to be reused. You need to deal with that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You specified in the comments that you aren't relying on the results on the `UPDATE`. With that I mind, I think the most efficient but straightforward solution is to use the [`COPY FROM`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) helper in conjunction with something like [CSV Writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to bulk insert the data into a temporary table. From this temporary table you can run the update after a certain number of rows have been written to it. Temporary tables are only visible per connection, so if using a [connection pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html) the temporary table will be removed when the connection is closed.

Downside of this approach is that you will lose some data if the application crashes before the bulk update operation completes. If you aren't waiting for each UPDATE to succeed before moving on to the next operation then that can happen regardless. Upside is that it will dramatically improve speed without needing to worry about all the complexities of trying to use psycopg2 asynchronously but still avoiding the excessive network roundtrips.